# How to get back start menu in Windows 8 Release Preview?

Tags: windows-8-preview, start-menu

How to get the start menu back in Windows 8 Release Preview? Previous [registry trick](https://superuser.com/questions/335766/how-can-i-revert-back-to-the-old-start-menu-in-windows-8) don't work for windows 8 release preview.

Also [ViStart](http://lee-soft.com/vistart/) is very slow and take much time on each startup.

**EDIT:** If it is not possible to enable, is there any alternate lightweight start menu app to do that?

Comment: Short version is that you can't

Comment: Metro *is* the start menu for Windows 8. Get used to it.

Comment: @RandolphWest Microsoft trained us on start menu for years and improved it as well in windows Vista. No one would have asked for start menu if metro was really better than start menu.

Comment: @LifeH2O Microsoft had backtracked on that. They have killed start menu entirely since usage of it is down. Pinning applications helped that. It's now been removed totally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been completely removed from the current previews of Windows 8. It will not be coming back from what I'm hearing from Microsoft

Answer (score 3):

If you do not use the mouse keystrokes are exactly the same. Hit the windows key and part of the program name and enter. Nothing has changed since Windows 7.

Comment: Launchy is an alternative app.

Comment: You don't type in windows, you press the windows key, small difference, which is reflected in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

A good lightweight alternate is [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/gallery.html). It supports themes as well.